# Why no tag Badges for Good questions

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, badges, stack-exchange, tag-badges

Why not make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) but for questions too?

I love that everything is well though behind SO but I can't see no reason as to why great questions can't be prized with "Badges by subject".

Comment: [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/788769/my-question-tag-scores) is a SEDE query, to at least count the question tag scores.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tag badges are designed to emphasize knowledge in a particular field. For good questions, there are already the Good Question, Notable Question, Famous Question, Stellar Question, and Popular Question badges. However, since questions indicate *lack* of knowledge in a particular field, there is no good reason to create these badges.

Also, since people love to try and get badges, this would cause a great increase in questions because of people trying to get these tag question badges, which simply prevents people who legitimately need their question answered from getting an answer.

Comment: Ok, I get you point. I just though it wouldn't be so bad to say ok user X you ask great questions about ... etc. Thanks!!

Comment: Lack of knowledge in particular field would give a bad/trivial question. Good question need good knowledge.