# Make tag badges count questions site-specifically

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, tag-badges, site-specific

<sup>As asked [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8118/44713), [here](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2330/178988), and probably a few more places.</sup>

Tag badges currently only are funded towards by votes on answers. However, on some sites, this is not appropriate.

For example, on [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), a great deal of work and knowledge over a tag is in writing questions; we have a user [(@HelkaHomba)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26997/helka-homba?tab=badges) who has written literally *hundreds* of questions in multiple tags and yet does not even have a single *bronze* tag-specific badge. However, as [@AlexA.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20469/alex-a) pointed out in the first link provided:

> I had a brief chat with a dev and apparently this can't be set on a per-site basis; the change would have to apply network-wide. He did recommend leaving this up and seeing what kind of support it gets though.

Since it is appropriate on *some* sites, but not others, making this set-able site-specifically (and then, of course, changing it site-per-site) would be best.

**EDIT:** As @MartinBüttner pointed out, it might be better to award tag badges for questions separately from tag badges for answers. Please consider this as another possible [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) candidate.

Comment: While this would be an even more significant change, I'd like to point out that I think for question-centric sites like PPCG [it might be even better to add a separate batch of tag badges that *only* count questions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8598/8478).

Comment: Making questions count toward badges has requested [here on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71603/287795), but that question did not ask for it to be implemented separately per site.

Comment: @AlexA. I found that and forgot to mention that in my post. :P Thanks